# What makes a background downloading task suspicious and how to make it less so?

Tags: security

**Short question:**

I have an application that fetches files from a cloud host. It looks suspicious to the security software and treated is as a virus.

What shall I do it make it get around the anti-virus software?

**Longer story**

I have a USB device and I need the firmware on it to be automatically updated.

When the device is connected to a computer, it presents itself as two removable USB mass storage devices.

The first one stores the application in question, the second is the place to put the upgrade package.

The user would go to the first partition and run the application, and while the user is doing his/her job with the application (like processing data collected by the device), the application fetches the upgrade package from an URL hosted in the cloud and places it in the second partition.

The device will upgrade itself when it's disconnected from the computer.

During this process, the application is isolated by the security software installed on the test machine.

**Problems**

This application raises a lot of red flags:

1. It runs from a removable USB drive
2. It starts downloading files from the internet without notifying the user.
3. The downloaded file is placed into another removable USB drive.

The operation, defined by the requirement, is suspicious itself. So I can imagine that an answer to this question is basically an answer to "how to get around a security software".

If this is the case, how shall I get the operating system or the user involved in the operation to make the application less suspicious?

**Background**

The application is written in C++/Qt.

The file being downloaded file is a linux opkg package with `-rw-rw-r--` permission.

The file is fetched from an HTTPS URL hosted on Amazon S3.

The test machines runs Windows 10.

Comment: Which security service?

Comment: @SilverlightFox Norton antivirus.